# White status bar with "App Scene WindowGroup"

Tags: swift, swiftui

With the new `App Scene WindowGroup` structure in Xcode 12, how can you specify the white status bar? I've searched around but so far have not been able to find an answer.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            AppView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the Apple Developer Forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658539

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in Xcode. form the left navigator(it is usually open, but if its not, you can open it by (command + 0) ) select Your_Project_Name.xcodeporj file (usually the first file, with a mainly blue foreground with appstore icon on it). select your ios-macos target from the targets (or any other targets which do have an status bar to configure). make sure youre on the `general` tab. one of the section should be `Development Info` which includes a `status bar` part. configure the status bar there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I tried that but it only changes the status bar to white during launch, once the app has launched it changes back to black